# Is there a way to organize Meteor templates so it isn't hard to figure out what's the data context?

Tags: meteor

As my Meteor project grows and I add more templates, partials and helpers, it gets harder to figure out what will be the data context for it. Then I'll have to `console.log(this)` inside a helper function to figure out what's the data I'm dealing with.

Does anybody have a naming scheme or any other strategy to handle this?

Or is this mess just a sign I'm failing to modularize stuff properly and should refactor everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, each module has a folder. Each folder contains `helpers.js`, `events.js`, the "ons" (`onCreated.js`, `onDestroyed.js`, `onRendered.js`) and finally `templates.html`. If your project is big, break these out into individual subfolders for the necessary CRUD actions (I have a `create` folder and an `update` folder because reading & deleting happens in the update templates.

My template names are long and verbose, but that's OK, WebStorm does a good job of guessing what I want. For example, if I had some infowindow that listed all the addresses associated with a client: `clientMap`, `clientMapPopup`, `clientMapPopupLocationList` `clientMapPopupLocationListItem`.

Regarding data context, it's usually pretty easy to see since my helper is the one that added something to the context. Although I honestly try to avoid using that unless I'm in an `{{#each}}` because IMHO things like grabbing grandparent context is neither elegant nor robust. Instead, I have a temporary module object that I create & destroy on route changes.

So if my global object is `Global = {}`. In the `onCreated` and `onDestroyed` I write `Global.Module = {}` Then, I can create all the module-scoped variables I want (ReactiveVars, ReactiveDicts, local collections, primitives, client markers object, etc).

All that said, doing what you do & looking at my schema js (e.g. `collections/clients.js`) is still the fastest/thoughtless way to see what you want & what you're currently getting.